# Select the unique value in Django

Tags: python, django

I have values `id, code, name, status, and user_id`

```
id    Code         name     status   last added

1     23-07-00001  red       1          2023-07-11 02:48:41.025713
2     23-07-00002  orange    2          2023-07-11 02:48:41.025713
3     23-07-00003  blue      3          2023-07-12 05:18:47.534430
4     23-07-00002  orange    4          2023-07-12 05:24:40.485039
```

Now I want output like this , the last added should retain

```
1     23-07-00001  red       1          2023-07-11 02:48:41.025713
3     23-07-00003  blue      3          2023-07-12 05:18:47.534430
4     23-07-00002  orange    4          2023-07-12 05:24:40.485039
```

I tried `distinct` this but it doesn't work, any solution will be appreciated its either it is written in a raw or default in django

```
item_data = TevIncoming.objects.filter(status__in=retrieve).select_related().values_list('code', flat=True).distinct().order_by('-incoming_in').reverse()
```

Comment: The thing is that all your entries are unique (difference in 'last added'). But I guess you actually want the newest entry for each 'Code'.

Comment: If I am correct you will want to 'filter(status__in=retrieve).latest(last added)' or something along this line https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Answer (score 0):

Your desired query is this, check it to see the output is as you wanted:

```py
from django.db.models import Max

item_data = (
    TevIncoming.objects
    .filter(status__in=retrieve)
    .values('code')
    .annotate(last_added=Max('last_added'))
    .order_by('-last_added')
)
```

also try this one:

```py
item_data = (
    TevIncoming.objects
    .filter(status__in=retrieve)
    .order_by('code', '-incoming_in')  # Sort by code ascending and incoming_in descending
    .distinct('code')  # Keep only the first unique occurrence of each code
    .select_related()
)
```

let me know which one has your desired output.

Comment: I think the second solution will work for me but I used mysql and I have error which is `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` the distinct did not recognize

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to archive those things like this. I created a model with only three fields **`(name, status, created_at)`**

##### models.py

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

##### views.py

```
def DemoView(request):
  color_list = [i[0] for i in DemoModel.objects.values_list('name').distinct()]
  data = DemoModel.objects.filter(name__in= color_list) 
  data = data.values('name').annotate(Max('created_at')).annotate(Max('status'))
  context = {'data':data}
  
  return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

##### record list in admin panel

[image]

##### HTML Output

[image]